# How to check if two files have the same content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compare, mocha.js, should.js

I am using `mocha/supertest/should.js` to test REST Service

`GET /files/<hash>` returns file as stream.

How can I assert in `should.js` that file contents are the same?

```
it('should return file as stream', function (done) {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('test/fixtures/tmp.json');
    
    var req = api.get('/files/676dfg1430af3595');
    req.on('end', function(){
       var tmpBuf = fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/tmp.json');
       var testBuf = fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/test.json');
    
       // How to assert with should.js file contents are the same (tmpBuf == testBuf )
       // ...
    
       done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Surprisingly, no one has suggested [Buffer.equals](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#buffer_buf_equals_otherbuffer). That seems to be the fastest and simplest approach and has been around since v0.11.

So your code would become `tmpBuf.equals(testBuf)`

Comment: The best solutions are the easiest

Comment: But what if the file size larger than RAM size?

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 solutions:

**First**:

Compare the result strings

```
tmpBuf.toString() === testBuf.toString();
```

**Second**:

Using a loop to read the buffers byte by byte

```
var index = 0,
    length = tmpBuf.length,
    match = true;

while (index < length) {
    if (tmpBuf[index] === testBuf[index]) {
        index++;
    } else {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}

match; // true -> contents are the same, false -> otherwise
```

**Third**:

Using a third-party module like [buffertools](https://www.npmjs.org/package/buffertools) and buffertools.compare(buffer, buffer|string) method.

Answer (score 4):

In `should.js` you can use `.eql` to compare Buffer's instances:

```
> var buf1 = new Buffer('abc');
undefined
> var buf2 = new Buffer('abc');
undefined
> var buf3 = new Buffer('dsfg');
undefined
> buf1.should.be.eql(buf1)
...
> buf1.should.be.eql(buf2)
...
> buf1.should.be.eql(buf3)
AssertionError: expected <Buffer 61 62 63> to equal <Buffer 64 73 66 67>
    ...
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution using `file-compare` and `node-temp`:

```
it('should return test2.json as a stream', function (done) {
    var writeStream = temp.createWriteStream();
    temp.track();

    var req = api.get('/files/7386afde8992');

    req.on('end', function() {
        comparator.compare(writeStream.path, TEST2_JSON_FILE, function(result, err) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            result.should.true;
            done();
        });
    });

    req.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

for comparing large files e.g. images when asserting file uploads a comparison of buffers or strings with `should.eql` takes ages. i recommend asserting the buffer hash with the *crypto* module:

```js
const buf1Hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(buf1).digest();
const buf2Hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(buf2).digest();
buf1Hash.should.eql(buf2Hash);
```

an easier approach is asserting the buffer length like so:

```js
buf1.length.should.eql(buf2.length)
```

instead of using *shouldjs* as assertion module you can surely use a different tool

Comment: Please do not use hashes. Hashes are usually, but *not always* unique due to the [Pigeon Hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) principle. Further, the computations required in order to generate the hash are far more expensive than simply comparing the original content.

Comment: Dude, sha256 is a cryptographically secure hash function. The probability of having 2 different files with the hash are so tiny that it is ridiculous to ever mention it.

Comment: The crypto lib has to go through all bytes to compute the hash. If you are already keeping both buffers entirely in memory, there's no point in computing their hashes. Directly comparing their contents is not only easier to read, but also faster (because you can skip the hash calculations). Hashes would be useful here only if the files are so big you can't keep them in memory to run the direct comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use [non-blocking calls](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking) in JavaScript to get a better performance, at least to prevent from blocking other operations:

> Blocking is when the execution of additional JavaScript in the Node.js process must wait until a non-JavaScript operation completes. This happens because the event loop is unable to continue running JavaScript while a blocking operation is occurring.
>
> In Node.js, JavaScript that exhibits poor performance due to being CPU intensive rather than waiting on a non-JavaScript operation, such as I/O, isn't typically referred to as blocking. Synchronous methods in the Node.js standard library that use libuv are the most commonly used blocking operations. Native modules may also have blocking methods.

So, I would change the `Sync` calls with something like the following code. Also, I would use the method `equals` that `Max` suggest to compare both files:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('file1', (err, data1) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.readFile('file2', (err, data2) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data1.equals(data2)) {
            console.log('EQUAL')
        } else {
            console.log('NON EQUAL')
        }

    });
});
```

Though for a small and a single script the result would be almost the same