# How to compare PDF using nightwatch.js

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I would like to compare two PDF during an automated test. One will be generate on a website, and the other one will be stored on my computer.
As I am a beginner in automation I would like to know if I can use Nightwatch during an existing test case to compare PDF during a new step.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783161/asserting-files-that-have-the-same-content help? If not, could you define by which means you want to compare these files?